# How to get values through list in django template using FOR loop?

Tags: python, html, mysql, django

```
{% for i in count %}
   var str2 = {{leds[i]}}
   var x = {{xpos[i]}}
   var y = {{ypos[i]}} 
   var w = 30
   var h = 30
   var fill = {{status[i]}}

   document.getElementById("FirstName").value = str2;
   document.getElementById("xposition").value = x;
   document.getElementById("yposition").value = y;
   document.getElementById("status").value = fill;

   add1(x,y,fill);
   i = i+1
{% endfor %}
```

In this code we want to traverse the leds, xpos, ypos lists by a for loop getting the values one by one. The error given is "Could not parse the remainder: '[i]' from 'leds[i]'". Any ideas?

Comment: What is `count`? The Django template language is different from Python -- including `i = i+1` doesn't affect the loop variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want something like this:

In your views.py:

```
stuff = zip(leds, xpos, ypos)
# and then pass this value to your template.
```

In your template:

```
{% for led, x, y in stuff %}
var str2 = "{{led}}"; // notice the quotes for the JS string.
var x = {{x}};
var y = {{y}};
```